# Ко многим через в laravel eloquent — как сделать хитрый запрос?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть 3 таблицы - доктора, клиенты, КлиентКурс, как связь клиента и некоего курса в системе.

```
doctor
    id - integer
    name - string

client_course
    id - integer
    course_id - integer
    doctor_id - integer
    client_id - integer

client
    id - integer
    name - string
```

То есть доктор назначается на конкретный курса, а не закрепляется за клиентом.
Как прокинуть связь, чтобы внутри модели доктора можно было зацепить всех клиентов, назначенных на курсы?
Я пробовал так:

```
public function clients() {
      return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Client', 'App\ClientCourse');
}
```

Но на это вылетает ошибка

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clients.client_course_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `clients`.*, `client_course`.`doctor_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `clients` inner join `client_course` on `client_course`.`id` = `clients`.`client_course_id` where `client_course`.`doctor_id` = 1)
```

Что я делаю не так? Можно ли при такой схеме прокинуть связь ко многим через?..
Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте `return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Client', 'App\ClientCourse', 'id');`